# How many images are formed when an object is placed between two plane mirrors with angle $72^\circ$?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, geometry

I'm a little confused here since there are varying answers on the internet, and I cannot find any legitimate sources explaining this problem.

According to what I've seen, the formula is simply
$$
N = \frac{360^\circ}{A} - 1
$$
However, other sources say that $N$ needs to be an odd number (I do not know why), so when $N$ is even, the answer is actually $N+1$.

If I used the first method, then the answer would be $N=\dfrac{360^\circ}{72^\circ}-1=4$. If I followed the second method, then the answer would be $N+1=5$. (I have actually found some people saying it's 4 and others saying it's 5.)

Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Can you upload question diagram.

Answer (score 2):

The images formed and the object will always lie on a circle. This interesting property can be utilised here.

[image]